# Start a thread for 5 times at the same time?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I want to execute a cmd command for five times at the same time. So i created a thread which exutes the command and started the thread for five times. Is this correct ?

```
MyRunnable r1 = new MyRunnable();
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            executor.execute(r1);
        }
```

.......

```
@Override
    public void run()
    {
        try {
            // Execute command
            String command = "cmd /c start cmd.exe";
            Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

            // Get output stream to write from it
            OutputStream out = child.getOutputStream();

            out.write("cd C:/ /r/n".getBytes());
            out.flush();
            out.write("dir /r/n".getBytes());
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) 
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i believe not. the execution time itself takes times. if i am not wrong, starting a normal Thread takes ~2 seconds

Comment: So what is the proper way to execute the threads for n times ?

Comment: @seriously Does it work?

Comment: @amirag He's using a fixed size thread pool. Also what are you basing your ~2 seconds on?

Comment: yes, actually its working. But is this the right way ?

Comment: @Kayaman in the past i built something and it took 2 seconds to start the second thread after the first one, i ran it few times and it was about this time everytime

Comment: @amirag You shouldn't draw too wide conclusions based on something you wrote and ran a few times.

Comment: I guess it's fine but an Executor doesn't really guarantee you that it's going to use all 5 threads it has in parallel. It will in practice but I would consider to use manual `new Thread` if you care about semantics. - @amirag starting threads takes milli or micro seconds. Whatever you measured was not the time it took to start a thread.

Comment: @Kayaman i guess you are right. should have checked it better

Comment: @zapl Do you have a source for a fixed size thread pool not guaranteeing executing them all in parallel?

Comment: @Kayaman The opposite: I don't have documentation that it guarantees it. It just guarantees that it's going to execute the code for me but not so much how, in which order, etc. If tasks are super quick, they might end up in 1 thread.

Comment: @zapl Eh... well. I think he just wanted to run them "at the same time", not specifically in different threads.

Comment: @Kayaman That's what I meant with "if you care about semantics". There is in practice no observable difference unless you start to make assumptions about `ThreadLocal`, your thread id, or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't well understand, what you mean uder the "correct" in your question.

If you asks, whether this code works? Then answer is yes.

Will this code, possibly, cause some problems? Then answer is yes too.

If your runnable object has some common state(some class level fields) they could become corrrupted since multiple threads will be able to modify it.

If your runnable is stateless and all it's variables are declared within a method scope, then everything could be ok, until one day someone will add a class level variable... And will possible get a very strange application behaviour or even worse - some production errors, which will be quite hard to find and debug. To prevent such a behaviour, you have to create a new runnable class instance for every thread you start.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using, MyRunnable r1 = new MyRunnable();
use Runnable r1 = new MyRunnable();

To execute the thread, we could either use execute() method or submit().
Your code looks good to me.

Make sure ExecutorService is closed. To close down the ExecutorService, shutdown()\ shutdownNow() can be used.
Additionally awaitTermination() can be used in order to wait until all threads are terminated.